# jQuery AJAX received data is null outside of the success-handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider this code example:

```
var source = null;

$.ajax({
    [...],
    success:function(data)
    {
        source = data;
        alert(source);
    }
});

alert(source);
```

Now: inside of the success handler, everything is fine, I get the correct data from the webservice and everything is just great. But as soon as JS leaves the $.ajax and is done with it the variable source is null again.

Tell me why. It must be some JavaScript specfic stuff I'm not familiar with. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably because you are forgetting AJAX is asynchronous. The `source` variable will be `undefined` until the `success` callback is completed.

Doing `alert(source)` beneath that code (outside of the `$.ajax()`) is almost guaranteed to be `undefined`.

Comment: @prc322 You can may it synchronous, but don't do it, you'll lock the browser whilst it is making the XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure the success callback is called before the alert outside of the ajax call is triggered?

The ajax call is asynchronous and returns immediately.